# VS2015 Error list does not get refreshed in real-time

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

With `VS2013(C#, ASP.NET Web-Form application)`

if I type the Following:

```
M=5
```

I immediately see the errors displayed on the Errors windows:

```
; expected
name M does not exist
```

With `VS2015` unless I Build the application nothing is shown, which is quite annoying for a large application.

I tried to see if there is a setting under tools/options but could not find any.

Are you aware of such settings or this behavior is per design?